# Put List's Data in RegBusinessObject

Tags: c#, list, winforms, report, stimulsoft

i want put data from ***listview*** into ***list of human***,then put list of human into the `RegBusinessObject` in `stimulsoft` for prepare a report but i don't know how.

```
List<human> humanslist = new List<human>();

                foreach (ListViewItem item in ListView.Items)
                {
                    humanslist.Add(new human{Name = item.SubItems[1].Text,});
                }

                StiReport stiReport = new StiReport();

                stiReport.Load(Application.StartupPath + "\\Reports\\humansReport.mrt");

                List<human> humanlistforstimulsoft = humanslist;

                stiReport.RegBusinessObject("HumanDetails", humanlistforstimulsoft);

                stiReport.ResetRenderedState();
                stiReport.Render();
                stiReport.Show();
```

i try top code but i get weird error:

```
System.Exception: 
'c:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2m1f2ast.0.cs(131,81) : error CS1026: ) 
expectedc:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2m1f2ast.0.cs(131,96) : error CS1002:;
expectedc:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2m1f2ast.0.cs(131,104) : error CS1002:; expectedc:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2m1f2ast.0.cs(131,104) : error CS1525: Invalid expression term ')'
c:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2m1f2ast.0.cs(131,105) : error CS1002: ;
expectedc:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2m1f2ast.0.cs(131,105) : error CS1525: Invalid expression term ')'
c:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2m1f2ast.0.cs(143,44) : error CS1026: ) expectedc:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2m1f2ast.0.cs(143,58) : error CS1002: ; expectedc:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2m1f2ast.0.cs(143,62) : error CS1002: ; expectedc:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2m1f2ast.0.cs(143,62) : error CS1525: Invalid expression term ','
c:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2m1f2ast.0.cs(143,64) : error CS1002: ; expectedc:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2m1f2ast.0.cs(143,68) : error CS1002: ; expectedc:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2m1f2ast.0.cs(143,68) : error CS1525: Invalid expression term ')'
c:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2m1f2ast.0.cs(341,46) : error CS1026: ) expectedc:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2m1f2ast.0.cs(341,50) : error CS1002: ; expectedc:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2m1f2ast.0.cs(341,50) : error CS1525: Invalid expression term ','
c:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2m1f2ast.0.cs(341,52) : error CS1002: ; expectedc:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2m1f2ast.0.cs(341,56) : error CS1002: ; expectedc:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2m1f2ast.0.cs(341,56) : error CS1525: Invalid expression term ')'
c:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2m1f2ast.0.cs(377,46) : error CS1026: ) expectedc:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2m1f2ast.0.cs(377,59) : error CS1041: Identifier expected; 'true' is a keywordc:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2m1f2ast.0.cs(377,63) : error CS1002: ; expectedc:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2m1f2ast.0.cs(377,63) : error CS1525: Invalid expression term ')'
c:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2m1f2ast.0.cs(383,46) : error CS1026: ) expectedc:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2m1f2ast.0.cs(383,65) : error CS1041: Identifier expected; 'true' is a keywordc:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2m1f2ast.0.cs(383,69) : error CS1002: ; expectedc:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2m1f2ast.0.cs(383,69) : error CS1525: Invalid expression term ')'
c:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2m1f2ast.0.cs(389,46) : error CS1026: ) expectedc:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2m1f2ast.0.cs(389,53) : error CS1002: ; expectedc:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2m1f2ast.0.cs(389,53) : error CS1525: Invalid expression term ','
c:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2m1f2ast.0.cs(389,55) : error CS1002: ; expectedc:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2m1f2ast.0.cs(389,59) : error CS1002: ; expectedc:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2m1f2ast.0.cs(389,59) : error CS1525: Invalid expression term ')'
c:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2m1f2ast.0.cs(395,46) : error CS1026: ) expectedc:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2m1f2ast.0.cs(395,60) : error CS1041: Identifier expected; 'true' is a keywordc:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2m1f2ast.0.cs(395,64) : error CS1002: ; expectedc:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Temp\2m1f2ast.0.cs(395,64) : error CS1525: Invalid expression term ')''
```

what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing parantheses when creating an instance of the `human` class. Try something like `new human()`...

Comment: @HSBgdan if you mean add parantheses to `humanslist.Add(new human(){Name = item.SubItems[1].Text,});`,i do it but it still does not work.